# openstack glace unknown command

Tags: openstack

every image related command I use ends up with an error:

```
glance image-create --name='Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 Server' --disk-format=qcow2 --container-format=bare --public < precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
```

> > Usage: glance  [options] [args]
>
> Commands:
>
> ```
> help <command>  Output help for one of the commands below
>
> add             Adds a new image to Glance
>
> update          Updates an image's metadata in Glance
>
> delete          Deletes an image from Glance
>
> index           Return brief information about images in Glance
>
> details         Return detailed information about images in
>                 Glance
>
> show            Show detailed information about an image in
>                 Glance
>
> clear           Removes all images and metadata from Glance
> ```
>
> Member Commands:
>
> ```
> image-members    List members an image is shared with
>
> member-images    List images shared with a member
>
> member-add       Grants a member access to an image
>
> member-delete    Revokes a member's access to an image
>
> members-replace  Replaces all membership for an image
> ```
>
> glance: error: no such option: --name

Cut down the above command and got this:

```
glance image-create
```

> > Usage: glance  [options] [args]
>
> Commands:
>
> ```
> help <command>  Output help for one of the commands below
>
> add             Adds a new image to Glance
>
> update          Updates an image's metadata in Glance
>
> delete          Deletes an image from Glance
>
> index           Return brief information about images in Glance
>
> details         Return detailed information about images in
>                 Glance
>
> show            Show detailed information about an image in
>                 Glance
>
> clear           Removes all images and metadata from Glance
> ```
>
> Member Commands:
>
> ```
> image-members    List members an image is shared with
>
> member-images    List images shared with a member
>
> member-add       Grants a member access to an image
>
> member-delete    Revokes a member's access to an image
>
> members-replace  Replaces all membership for an image
> ```
>
> Unknown command: image-create

I can't figure it out.

**NOTE: I'm using a VM running Ubuntu Precise and python-glanceclient is no longer available for it.**

Comment: You are probably using a very old version of `python-glanceclient`, because the command `image-create` is not available. Please post the output of `glance --version`. Instead of using `image-create` you should try using `add` (`add` is deprecated in newer `python-glanceclient` versions). Use `glance help add` to get further details.

Answer (score 0):

For your first command, you are using the '=' character, which is not required. Note the glance image-create command help:

```
usage: glance image-create [--id <IMAGE_ID>] [--name <NAME>] [--store <STORE>]
                           [--disk-format <DISK_FORMAT>]
                           [--container-format <CONTAINER_FORMAT>]
                           [--owner <TENANT_ID>] [--size <SIZE>]
                           [--min-disk <DISK_GB>] [--min-ram <DISK_RAM>]
                           [--location <IMAGE_URL>] [--file <FILE>]
                           [--checksum <CHECKSUM>] [--copy-from <IMAGE_URL>]
                           [--is-public {True,False}]
                           [--is-protected {True,False}]
                           [--property <key=value>] [--human-readable]
                           [--progress]
```

The second command should be valid. You may want to reinstall the glance commands. Try installing it using pip:

```
sudo pip install python-glanceclient
```

Comment: '=' is optional and I cant locate python-glanceclient but have already reinstalled every glance related package available on repos.